# vim in 14.04 (Trusty) starts up in Replace mode

Tags: 14.04, vim, vimrc

I just deployed a handful of 14.04 systems and I'm noticing that whenever I `vim` something, vim is already in replace mode.

As I'm used to being in command mode on starting, this is rather disorienting.

Any idea why? I don't see any obvious culprits in `/etc/vim/vimrc`, but this happens with every user on the system.

Installed relevant packages:

```
$ aptitude search vim | grep ^i
i   vim                             - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
i   vim-common                      - Vi IMproved - Common files
i   vim-nox                         - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with sc
i   vim-runtime                     - Vi IMproved - Runtime files
i   vim-tiny                        - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact
```

`vim -V` output:

```
# vim -V
chdir(/usr/share/vim)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "$VIM/vimrc"
Searching for "debian.vim" in "/root/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/root/.vim/after"
Searching for "/root/.vim/debian.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/debian.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 10: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
continuing in /usr/share/vim/vimrc
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/debian.vim"
Searching for "/root/.vim/after/debian.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 20: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim"
Searching for "syntax/synload.vim" in "/root/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/root/.vim/after"
Searching for "/root/.vim/syntax/synload.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/syntax/synload.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax/synload.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 19: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim"
Searching for "syntax/syncolor.vim" in "/root/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/root/.vim/after"
Searching for "/root/.vim/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 21: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
continuing in /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/root/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
continuing in /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
Searching for "filetype.vim" in "/root/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/root/.vim/after"
Searching for "/root/.vim/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 25: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim"
Searching for "ftdetect/*.vim" in "/root/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/root/.vim/after"
Searching for "/root/.vim/ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "/root/.vim/after/ftdetect/*.vim"
not found in 'runtimepath': "ftdetect/*.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
continuing in /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/root/.vim/after/filetype.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
continuing in /usr/share/vim/vimrc
Searching for "syntax/syncolor.vim" in "/root/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/root/.vim/after"
Searching for "/root/.vim/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 25: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
continuing in /usr/share/vim/vimrc
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/root/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "filetype.vim" in "/root/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/root/.vim/after"
Searching for "/root/.vim/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 36: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
continuing in /usr/share/vim/vimrc
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/root/.vim/after/filetype.vim"
Searching for "ftplugin.vim" in "/root/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/root/.vim/after"
Searching for "/root/.vim/ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 36: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
continuing in /usr/share/vim/vimrc
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "/root/.vim/after/ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "indent.vim" in "/root/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/root/.vim/after"
Searching for "/root/.vim/indent.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/indent.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/indent.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 36: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
continuing in /usr/share/vim/vimrc
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/indent.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/indent.vim"
Searching for "/root/.vim/after/indent.vim"
finished sourcing $VIM/vimrc
chdir(/root)
fchdir() to previous dir
could not source "$HOME/.vimrc"
chdir(/root/.vim)
fchdir() to previous dir
could not source "~/.vim/vimrc"
chdir(/root)
fchdir() to previous dir
could not source "$HOME/.exrc"
Searching for "plugin/**/*.vim" in "/root/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/root/.vim/after"
Searching for "/root/.vim/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/**/*.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "/root/.vim/after/plugin/**/*.vim"
Reading viminfo file "/root/.viminfo" info oldfiles
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: can you post the output of `vim -V`

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when you `vim` a file or run `vim` with no file? Can you escape from insert mode back to command mode? Does running `vim -u none` change anything? Is `vim` a shell alias or function, does running `/usr/bin/vim` do the same thing?

Comment: Same behavior with or without a file. ESC does work to exit replace mode. `vim -u none` generates a "can't read from none" error, but it comes up in command mode like it should! `/usr/bin/vim`, problem still happens.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `vim -u NONE` to skip reading all initialization vimrc files. But if `vim -u none` made it work, that points to it being something in either `~/.vimrc` or in the system `/etc/vim/vimrc` or `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your locale set correctly?

I was having this problem until a few minutes ago, I eventually traced it to misconfigured locales.

Fixed the config files and ran `locale-gen`, then `source /etc/profile` (or better, reboot) and vim behaved properly. No more starting up in replace mode.

I'm on Arch linux so I won't post the exact steps, but maybe you have a variation on the same problem.

Comment: That was it! Something during my autoinstall process left the system locale as EN-GB rather than EN-US, which was causing some rather interesting problems elsewhere in the system as well.

Comment: "Fixed the config files", huh?

Answer (score -1):

Try using this command

```
$ sudo apt-get remove vim
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

even if you are using a different version of ubunutu, this version of vim is the best for ubuntu

Comment: I've tested running vim (the command line version) after switching to vim-gnome, and it definitely does not fix this problem.